# I want to delete an item from a list view

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, listadapter

The problem I'm having is that whenever I delete , only the last item from the `ListView` is being deleted. I remove the item from my arraylist and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. Is there anything which I'm missing? Also , when I try to delete too many items I get an `arrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception , but I'm passing the index I recieve. Why  I am getting this exception?

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
            HistoryItem item = historyItems.get(index);
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    //ToDo edit
                    //Toast.makeText(History.this,"pos "+position+" index "+index,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //ToDo delete

                    historyItems.remove(item);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: try removing item by index like `historyItems.remove(position);`

Comment: Check if the index is correct or not

Comment: The toast that i had commented in case 0 gave me index as 0 and position as 1 for the first item...so i don't think i should remove using the position...

Comment: @sharanggupta please check their [demo](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/baoyz/swipemenulistview/demo/SimpleActivity.java) index is used to recognize which view is clicked and position is used for which row is clicked.

Comment: Thanks @Kaushik!!!! I cant believe I made this mistake!!! I was mislead by the name index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `index` use `position`

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
                HistoryItem item = historyItems.get(position);
                switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                        //ToDo edit
                        //Toast.makeText(History.this,"pos "+position+" index "+index,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        //ToDo delete

                        historyItems.remove(position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using index which is position of Edit or Delete buttons..
You have to use Position instead of index to delete item from list
The problem is at `HistoryItem item = historyItems.get(index);`

Solution:

```
HistoryItem item = historyItems.get(position);
```

Comment: Thank yuo for clearing it up!!! Im sorry i cannot upvote , my reputation is too low...

Comment: No prob m8 . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You are using index variable to remove items. You need to use position variable to get the selected items from history list

Change this line in code

```
HistoryItem item = historyItems.get(position);
```